# How to automate the transformation of a list to numeric values

Tags: r, list, vector, numeric

Imagine I have the following `data.frame` in R:

```
;Label;PennElementName;Parameter;EventTime;grupo;item;frases;tags;valores
1;minhasfrases;mouse;Move;1621714127287;A;1;Esse aviso não está vazio e eu preciso clicar logo sobre ele.;timestamps;0, 306, 321, 338, 355, 372, 388, 406, 422, 439, 455, 622, 638, 656, 705, 721, 755, 805, 822, 5189, 5206, 5223, 5238, 5255, 5271, 5288, 5305, 5321, 5338, 5355, 5371, 5388, 5405, 5488, 5505, 5521, 5538, 5555, 5572, 5588, 5605, 5622, 5655
2;minhasfrases;mouse;Move;1621714133140;A;2;Esse aviso está vazio e eu também preciso clicar sobre ele.;timestamps;0, 168, 185, 201, 219, 235, 252, 268, 285, 302, 318, 336, 352, 369, 385, 402, 418, 668, 685, 702, 720, 736, 752, 769, 835, 852, 4652, 4669, 4686, 4702, 4719, 4736, 4752, 4769, 4785, 4802, 4819, 4835, 4852, 4868, 4886, 4902, 4918, 4935, 4952, 4969, 4985, 5002, 5018, 5035
3;minhasfrases;mouse;Move;1621714127287;A;1;Esse aviso não está vazio e eu preciso clicar logo sobre ele.;xpos;864, 865, 878, 892, 896, 896, 891, 882, 882, 882, 882, 882, 879, 878, 877, 876, 875, 874, 873, 875, 897, 940, 972, 1002, 1028, 1048, 1054, 1057, 1061, 1063, 1064, 1067, 1068, 1069, 1070, 1073, 1074, 1077, 1080, 1083, 1084, 1085, 1085
4;minhasfrases;mouse;Move;1621714133140;A;2;Esse aviso está vazio e eu também preciso clicar sobre ele.;xpos;1085, 1085, 1079, 1060, 1039, 1006, 982, 960, 937, 911, 875, 855, 848, 848, 851, 855, 855, 861, 866, 871, 876, 878, 878, 879, 879, 879, 878, 847, 814, 780, 740, 702, 676, 657, 630, 611, 589, 568, 540, 518, 496, 483, 477, 473, 467, 460, 447, 435, 431, 430
5;minhasfrases;mouse;Move;1621714127287;A;1;Esse aviso não está vazio e eu preciso clicar logo sobre ele.;ypos;416, 415, 383, 339, 291, 242, 199, 167, 161, 158, 156, 156, 157, 157, 157, 158, 158, 159, 160, 192, 263, 365, 428, 492, 540, 573, 590, 597, 602, 605, 607, 611, 613, 619, 633, 647, 655, 659, 663, 668, 670, 670, 671
6;minhasfrases;mouse;Move;1621714133140;A;2;Esse aviso está vazio e eu também preciso clicar sobre ele.;ypos;671, 670, 666, 643, 615, 564, 517, 451, 374, 292, 200, 155, 126, 113, 109, 106, 105, 123, 137, 146, 154, 158, 162, 164, 166, 167, 168, 213, 256, 300, 342, 386, 419, 440, 477, 513, 546, 568, 579, 585, 591, 597, 601, 604, 613, 620, 627, 635, 639, 640
```

The last column, named "Valores" is, in fact, a string of characters (notice that these data are `comma separated value` while the columns are separated with semicolon - use `readcsv2()` to load the date in R).

What I want to do is **to automate the transformation of this last column in numeric values** and make it a longer table. By using the code below, I was able to make that transformation for this table with 6 rows, but I want to do that for a column with `n` rows. That's the code I've used:

```
# extracting vectors as numeric itens
for(k in 1:length(results$valores)){
  assign(paste0("obi_", k),
         as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(results$valores[[k]], split = ", "))))

  }

# defining same length of vector to cbind them 
lengths <- max(c(length(obi_1), length(obi_2), length(obi_3), length(obi_4), length(obi_5), length(obi_5)))

length(obi_1) <- lengths
length(obi_2) <- lengths
length(obi_3) <- lengths
length(obi_4) <- lengths
length(obi_5) <- lengths
length(obi_6) <- lengths

df <- data.frame(obi_1, obi_2, obi_3, obi_4, obi_5, obi_6)

# binding the transpose of the results  
results <- cbind(results, t(df))

results <- results %>%
  gather("cols", "values", '1':ncol(results)) %>%
  select(-c(valores, cols))
```

And that's a demonstration of the final table (the main columns are the last couple ones):

```
,Label,PennElementName,Parameter,EventTime,grupo,item,frases,tags,values
1,minhasfrases,mouse,Move,1621714127287,A,1,Esse aviso não está vazio e eu preciso clicar logo sobre ele.,timestamps,0
2,minhasfrases,mouse,Move,1621714133140,A,2,Esse aviso está vazio e eu também preciso clicar sobre ele.,timestamps,0
3,minhasfrases,mouse,Move,1621714127287,A,1,Esse aviso não está vazio e eu preciso clicar logo sobre ele.,xpos,864
4,minhasfrases,mouse,Move,1621714133140,A,2,Esse aviso está vazio e eu também preciso clicar sobre ele.,xpos,1085
5,minhasfrases,mouse,Move,1621714127287,A,1,Esse aviso não está vazio e eu preciso clicar logo sobre ele.,ypos,416
6,minhasfrases,mouse,Move,1621714133140,A,2,Esse aviso está vazio e eu também preciso clicar sobre ele.,ypos,671
7,minhasfrases,mouse,Move,1621714127287,A,1,Esse aviso não está vazio e eu preciso clicar logo sobre ele.,timestamps,306
8,minhasfrases,mouse,Move,1621714133140,A,2,Esse aviso está vazio e eu também preciso clicar sobre ele.,timestamps,168
9,minhasfrases,mouse,Move,1621714127287,A,1,Esse aviso não está vazio e eu preciso clicar logo sobre ele.,xpos,865
10,minhasfrases,mouse,Move,1621714133140,A,2,Esse aviso está vazio e eu também preciso clicar sobre ele.,xpos,1085
11,minhasfrases,mouse,Move,1621714127287,A,1,Esse aviso não está vazio e eu preciso clicar logo sobre ele.,ypos,415
12,minhasfrases,mouse,Move,1621714133140,A,2,Esse aviso está vazio e eu também preciso clicar sobre ele.,ypos,670
```

I think that my greatest difficulty is to understand how to automate the part of the code after the `for` loop.

I hope I could make myself clear. Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: Please add your data by pasting the output of dput(data). It is much easier to help you with readily available data.
For the demonstration of the final table, please paste dput(final_table) or, if it is too long, dput(head(final_table, 10)), or paste the output from your console, instead of providing a csv

Comment: What do you mean by "how to automate?"

Comment: Maybe if you just wrap all your code inside a custom function? Somthing like `my_function<-function(results, valores){for(k in 1:length(results$valores)){.....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Group by all columns except valores and use group_modify to scan that column in.

```
library(dplyr)

Scan <- function(x) scan(text = x, sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)

DF %>%
 group_by(across(-valores)) %>%
 group_modify(~ data.frame(valores = Scan(.$valores))) %>%
 ungroup
```

**2)** or using Scan from above create a list column and then unnest it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(valores = list(Scan(valores))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  unnest(valores)
```

### Note

DF shown reproducibly is:

```
Lines <- ";Label;PennElementName;Parameter;EventTime;grupo;item;frases;tags;valores
1;minhasfrases;mouse;Move;1621714127287;A;1;Esse aviso não está vazio e eu preciso clicar logo sobre ele.;timestamps;0, 306, 321, 338, 355, 372, 388, 406, 422, 439, 455, 622, 638, 656, 705, 721, 755, 805, 822, 5189, 5206, 5223, 5238, 5255, 5271, 5288, 5305, 5321, 5338, 5355, 5371, 5388, 5405, 5488, 5505, 5521, 5538, 5555, 5572, 5588, 5605, 5622, 5655
2;minhasfrases;mouse;Move;1621714133140;A;2;Esse aviso está vazio e eu também preciso clicar sobre ele.;timestamps;0, 168, 185, 201, 219, 235, 252, 268, 285, 302, 318, 336, 352, 369, 385, 402, 418, 668, 685, 702, 720, 736, 752, 769, 835, 852, 4652, 4669, 4686, 4702, 4719, 4736, 4752, 4769, 4785, 4802, 4819, 4835, 4852, 4868, 4886, 4902, 4918, 4935, 4952, 4969, 4985, 5002, 5018, 5035
3;minhasfrases;mouse;Move;1621714127287;A;1;Esse aviso não está vazio e eu preciso clicar logo sobre ele.;xpos;864, 865, 878, 892, 896, 896, 891, 882, 882, 882, 882, 882, 879, 878, 877, 876, 875, 874, 873, 875, 897, 940, 972, 1002, 1028, 1048, 1054, 1057, 1061, 1063, 1064, 1067, 1068, 1069, 1070, 1073, 1074, 1077, 1080, 1083, 1084, 1085, 1085
4;minhasfrases;mouse;Move;1621714133140;A;2;Esse aviso está vazio e eu também preciso clicar sobre ele.;xpos;1085, 1085, 1079, 1060, 1039, 1006, 982, 960, 937, 911, 875, 855, 848, 848, 851, 855, 855, 861, 866, 871, 876, 878, 878, 879, 879, 879, 878, 847, 814, 780, 740, 702, 676, 657, 630, 611, 589, 568, 540, 518, 496, 483, 477, 473, 467, 460, 447, 435, 431, 430
5;minhasfrases;mouse;Move;1621714127287;A;1;Esse aviso não está vazio e eu preciso clicar logo sobre ele.;ypos;416, 415, 383, 339, 291, 242, 199, 167, 161, 158, 156, 156, 157, 157, 157, 158, 158, 159, 160, 192, 263, 365, 428, 492, 540, 573, 590, 597, 602, 605, 607, 611, 613, 619, 633, 647, 655, 659, 663, 668, 670, 670, 671
6;minhasfrases;mouse;Move;1621714133140;A;2;Esse aviso está vazio e eu também preciso clicar sobre ele.;ypos;671, 670, 666, 643, 615, 564, 517, 451, 374, 292, 200, 155, 126, 113, 109, 106, 105, 123, 137, 146, 154, 158, 162, 164, 166, 167, 168, 213, 256, 300, 342, 386, 419, 440, 477, 513, 546, 568, 579, 585, 591, 597, 601, 604, 613, 620, 627, 635, 639, 640"
DF <- read.csv2(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyr::separate_rows`

```
tidyr::separate_rows(df, valores, sep = ',\\s', convert = TRUE)

# A tibble: 279 x 10
#       X Label  PennElementName Parameter  EventTime grupo  item frases    tags  valores
#   <int> <chr>  <chr>           <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <int> <chr>     <chr>   <int>
# 1     1 minha… mouse           Move         1.62e12 A         1 Esse avi… time…       0
# 2     1 minha… mouse           Move         1.62e12 A         1 Esse avi… time…     306
# 3     1 minha… mouse           Move         1.62e12 A         1 Esse avi… time…     321
# 4     1 minha… mouse           Move         1.62e12 A         1 Esse avi… time…     338
# 5     1 minha… mouse           Move         1.62e12 A         1 Esse avi… time…     355
# 6     1 minha… mouse           Move         1.62e12 A         1 Esse avi… time…     372
# 7     1 minha… mouse           Move         1.62e12 A         1 Esse avi… time…     388
# 8     1 minha… mouse           Move         1.62e12 A         1 Esse avi… time…     406
# 9     1 minha… mouse           Move         1.62e12 A         1 Esse avi… time…     422
#10     1 minha… mouse           Move         1.62e12 A         1 Esse avi… time…     439
# … with 269 more rows
```

Comment: Great answer too! You solved the problem with one row of code while I was caught in a misleading line of thought. I really appreciate your help!